# YouTube app bug "Connection to Server Lost"

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, youtube, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

YouTube app says "Connection to server Lost/ Tap to retry" When a video is played. The same bug presented itself on 3 different devices with the youtube app version(5.7.38) as the only common feature.

Samsung Galaxy S Duos|JB 4.2.1
Micromax Canvas HD|JB 4.2.1
Asus Nexus 7|KK 4.4.4

Rest of the features are working so its not a network problem. Even YouTube ads play, but not the videos.

The problem is same on both WiFi and Data

Similar questions have been asked before but the troubleshooting methods DO NOT work.
Any help woild be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to know which troubleshooting steps you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

**Clear cache** and **data** of *YouTube* and *Google play services*. It is recommended to do this provided you have a high speed WiFi/data access. These apps may download approximately 70-80 MB after clearing their data.

Steps:

- Disconnect all data connectivity. i.e. WiFi & mobile data.
- Go to your phone's 'Settings'.
- Click on 'Apps'.
- Scroll down to YouTube and click on it.
- Click on following buttons in order: 'Force Stop' > 'Clear Cache' > 'Clear Data'.
- Press 'back' button to come back to application list.
- Scroll up for 'Google Play services'.
- Do same again in order: 'Force Stop' > 'Clear Cache' > 'Clear Data'.
- Restart your device.
- Switch on your data connectivity. i.e. WiFi/Mobile data.
- Open Play Store and wait until everything successfully loads up.
- Now exit from Play Store and open up your YouTube app. It should probably work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps to make sure whether the problem lies with your video or the application-

1. Try to update the App from the Play Store if available.
2. After the update power off your device and wait for few minutes.(2-3 minutes max)
3. Power on your device and open your app and check for any other video
   is it able to play or not(from the start till the end).
4. If the video is able to play then the problem lies with your video which you are trying to view as it might be blocked or censored in your Country.
5. If most of the videos are not playing and showing the same error
   then
       you need to have a follow up with the You Tube support team with the video link
       and the device specifications.

Comment: I trie uninstalling updates and updated the app again. Tried many different videos. Doesnt work, unfortunately.

Comment: @KnIn then you need to do the last step

Answer (score 0):

I faced this bug when my YouTube app was outdated. Try to update your YouTube app and/or Google Play Services to the latest version, as YouTube depends on it.